# A deleted question is shown to me as incorrectly flagged as spam

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

Come on, what's the matter?

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232400/getting-wrong-absolute-path-for-migrated-wordpress-website)
[My flagging history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/443685)

Comment: Exactly how is that question [spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming)?

Comment: with an unnecesary link as "you can see the error on my site"

Comment: That's not spam.

Comment: Also: a two-year-old active member of the site, with over 2000 reputation, is probably not a spammer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to flag every post you run across where the author merely mentions their website in the body. **That's an inappropriate use of spam flags** and I'm surprised a lot more of them haven't been declined.

Referencing their own website to describe a problem may not be the *best* method of identifying that problem, and is grounds for closure since the problem could easily disappear in the future (especially if they get a solution). However, the mere fact that there is a URL in the post does **not** make it spam.

Spam flags can have severe consequences on the author of the post, such as a -100 reputation penalty or even IP throttling. Only use them in cases where it is a blatant unsolicited advertisement.

Answer (score 12):

Spam is **[unsolicited commercial advertisement.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming)**

Any other use of the spam flag (including its abuse as a synonym for "I don't like this post," "This person is shouting," or whatever) subjects your flag to being declined.

[**Example of spam:**](http://www.todayifoundout.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/spam5.jpg)

> Try my new hair care product! [link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.roosterteeth.com/images/ONEIDA4a8f92aa3dab0.jpg)

[**Not Spam:**](http://www.sfexaminer.com/imager/the-suspect-and-the-officer-pursuing-him-evidently-shared-a-taste-for-good/b/original/2318653/deb8/Steak_-_photos.com_.jpg)

> My website doesn't work, I can't foo the bar. [link](http://www.crummy.com/photos/2006/06-Worcester/09-The%20Foo%20Bar.jpg)

Comment: I totally disagree with the difference between both examples.  From the SEO point of view, they are just the same, but one will be accepted, so spammer wins

Comment: Oh, no.  If the post really needs to go, we'll delete it.  But your spam flag will still be declined if it's not actually spam.  Trust me, genuine spammers are not this smart anyway.

Comment: I'm not concerned about SEO.  If a user has a genuine programming problem and needs to link to their website to fully illustrate it, so be it.  If a user is posting thinly-veiled programming questions and trying to pass them off as spam, then cast a  *custom* moderator flag that says that.  *Communicate.*